# How can I find an analytic solution to a recursive sum such as this one?

Tags: summation, recursion

I am looking for a closed-form, analytic solution to the following recursive formula:

$g(m) = -\sigma + \frac{\sigma \kappa}{1 - \beta}\sum_{l=1}^{m}(1 - {\beta}^{l})g(m-l), \forall m>0$

where $g(0) = -\sigma$ - i.e. I am trying to find a general expression for $g(m)$. I tried to "find a pattern" by deriving g(1), g(2), etc. but I wasn't able to find one. I'm sure there is a method to solving equations such as this one, does anyone have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G(z) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty g(m) z^m$, and using your formula you should be able to write $G(z)$ as a rational function of $z$ with quadratic denominator.  The "closed form" expression for the Maclaurin series of this will be a bit complicated, involving the roots of that denominator.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I can get to $G(z) = \frac{-\sigma}{1-z} + \frac{\sigma \kappa}{1-\beta}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{l=1}^{m}(1-\beta^l)g(m-l)z^{m}$, but there the double summation is causing me headaches - how should I approach it so that I get the quadratic denominator that you mention? Also, when you mention the Maclaurin series, do you mean I should evaluate the Maclaurin series of $G(z)$ at zero and get $g(m)$ from that (knowing $G(0) = 0$)?

Comment: Write the double sum as $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{l=1}^\infty (1-\beta^l) g(k) z^{k+l} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty g(k) z^k \sum_{l=1}^\infty (1-\beta^l) z^l$$

Comment: Thank you, this is looking neat - I got that $G(z) = \frac{\sigma (\beta z - 1)}{(1-z)(1-\beta z) - \sigma \kappa z}$ - plugging in $z=0$ gives $g(0)=-\sigma$, as needed. But how do I proceed from here? How do I extract $g(m)$ using this formula? (I'm sorry, this method is new to me, that's why I'm struggling)

Comment: Write it with partial fractions as $$\frac{c_1}{z-r_1} + \frac{c_2}{z-r_2}$$ where $r_i$ are the roots of the denominator.  The series for these are well-known.